# How to xdg-open specific links with different apps

Tags: linux, url, xdg-open

Hi I want to open specific link with specific application. To be more specific, I want to open zoom links `https://us02web.zoom.us/j/something?pwd=somethingsomething` with desktop-ish zoom application (someting like pwa browser app, but not a native pwa app. Created with: -> three dots -> more tools -> create shortcut). Currently if I tell `xdg-open` to open this link it'll just send me to my default browser instead of zoom application. So how do I change it and is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open https://us02web.zoom.us/j/77479044122pwd=Nik0ajNiAWRkbXhkbWVJTXJtcklrQT09

translates to:

xdg-open zoommtg://us02web.zoom.us/join?action=join&confno=77479044122&pwd=Nik0ajNiAWRkbXhkbWVJTXJtcklrQT09

There's a bunch of other shite on the final URL, but I reckon that's all you need.

I divined this from moving `/usr/bin/xdg-open` to `/usr/bin/xdg-open.real` and changing `/usr/bin/xdg-open` to:

```
#!/bin/sh

logger -t xdg-open "$*" 

xdg-open.real "$*"
```

Then `chmod +x /usr/bin/xdg-open`

After that (and a URL or so) you can grep /var/log/syslog for `xdg-open` and see what happens.